# How to exit out of VSCode's Live Preview extension devtools pane windowed mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, live-preview

Whenever I click the vertical triple dot button in the live preview devtools, there is no longer an option to exit out of windowed mode. I want the devtools pane to be intergrated within the VSCode window, which I could do before, but now it seems like they removed that option? My live preview version is v0.4.4 and I tried reinstalling it but it didn't work.

Live preview devtools:

[image: Live preview devtools]

Chrome devtools:

[image: Chrome devtools]

Answer (score 0):

-Login Visual Studio Account
-you need to try .NET solutions (Change the project type what u selected)
-go for help - check updates